# AWS Athena restrict access to saved queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

One of my users need access to queries they saved in Athena but allowing the BatchGetNamedQuery permission shows all saved queries under that workgroup. Is there any way to restrict this to only allow the user to view queries they saved?

Comment: You can create multiple workgroups, each for a different team.